# How to display 1D array into 2D matrix form in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My question is entirely based on Template (HTML) in Angular. I don't want to convert any array permanently. I just want to display the same using some HTML trick. It's an array of objects.

```
kpi: { value: string; header: string; footer: string }[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.kpi.push(
    {
      value: "12",
      header: "Black",
      footer: "Grey"
    },
    {
      value: "23",
      header: "Orange",
      footer: "Green"
    },
    ...
);
```

The no. of objects i.e. elements will always be even. So the matrix will always be evenly distributed. Here's my template:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of kpi">
    <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let eachItem of row">
        <p>eachItem.value</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need `value` property only. The matrix ROW and COL can be kept in a variable for now. My code is not working. Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vmyzaf). Please help me.

Comment: You're saying it needs to be rendered in a matrix. But you aren't mentioning what constitutes the rows and columns. For eg. for the array of 6 elements, matrices could be of form 3x2 or 2x3. What is the deciding criteria?

Comment: Anything Michael. I mentioned that ROW and COL can be variables. Let them be 2 and 3 for now. I'll think about that later. Right now i just want to see the logic how matrix is created out of it. Thanks

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the number of rows and columns if you were to render a plain array as a matrix. Try the following

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  kpi: { value: string; header: string; footer: string }[] = [];

  ROW = 2;
  COL = 3;
  rows = this.getRange(this.ROW);
  cols = this.getRange(this.COL);
  values: Array<any>;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.kpi.push(...);
    console.log(this.kpi);
    this.values = this.kpi.map(t => t.value);  // <-- get list of values
  }

  private getRange(num: number) {
    return Array(num).fill(1).map((x, i) => i);
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <td class="col-12" *ngFor="let col of cols; let i=index">
            {{ values[row * COL + col] }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bw2sqy?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I'm looking into it. I'll get bcak to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use keyValuePipe. *ngFor directive not working for objects.

https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: I added the pipe but how to display it in matrix form? please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an auxiliar array using slice and map

```
splitInColumns(array,columns)
{ 
  return array
     .map((x,index)=>array.slice(index*columns,(index+1)*columns))
     .filter(x=>x.length)
}
```

And display as

```html
<div *ngFor="let group of arrayColumns">
  <span style="margin-right:1rem" *ngFor="let item of group">
      {{item.value}}
  </span>
</div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-44kda3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

If you want use bootstrap css, you can use ngClass and col-12, col-6,col-4.. but you need give a min width to the row

```html
<div class="row" style="min-width:200px">
    <div [ngClass]="columns==1?'col-12':
                    columns==2?'col-6':
                    columns==3?'col-4':
                    columns==4?'col-3':null"
        *ngFor="let item of array">
        {{item.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```